# n3k pause frame issue

Tags: cisco

We have 2x 10G (LACP) from our upstream that is connected to a n3k-c3064pq-10gx and on their switch they give us another 10g and we have monitor session from that 2x 10G (LACP) on this 10g port and currently we are receiving the following error log :

```
2020 Nov  4 11:57:36 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 234 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/2
2020 Nov  4 12:00:29 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 97 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/1
2020 Nov  4 12:05:29 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 144 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/1
2020 Nov  4 12:12:11 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 178 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/1
2020 Nov  4 12:14:23 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 100 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/2
2020 Nov  4 12:17:11 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 424 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/1
2020 Nov  4 12:19:23 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 1185 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/2
2020 Nov  4 12:22:11 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 1355 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/1
2020 Nov  4 12:27:12 X %-SLOT1-2-BCM_SYSLOG_LLFC_PAUSE_FRAME: 96 LLFC pause frames received on Ethernet1/1
```

it seems the port mirror send pause frame for our uplink so :

1. can we ignore this ? or this may cause issues for us?
2. how can we solve this?
   THank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal operation of Link Level Flow Control. If there is congestion on link pause frame will be sent which halts the transmission of the sender for a specified period of time. I think yours monitor session exhaust link capacity. To solve this issue I would consider adding another 10G port to LACP as the current setup isn't able to cope with capacity demand. To be sure you would need to closely monitor link utilization.

Comment: i have checked my port mirror and its around 7gbps and it has not reached close to 9g anytime also have disabled flow control and auto neg on my port mirror interface but its still exist

Comment: Flow control pause frame is sent from another switch, overwhelmed destination device would send a packet to the source indicating that the source should wait for a specific period of time to send the next packet. I assume another side cannot cope with traffic. Disabling flow control isn't the best option to do.

Comment: here is a simple topology :https://i.imgur.com/WCbqgUC.png, as you can see we have 2x 10g which is connected to the n3k and a 10g which is connected to port mirror server and all ports, has disabled flow control. so your mean is that 2k switch can not cop the traffic ?

Comment: as per your diagram pause frame does come from n2k switch. Is an n2k fabric extender (FEX) hooked to another switch? Disabling flow control will not resolve the issue it could make it worst.

Comment: yes its for my upstream and it seems n2k is connected to a 5672up switch, absolutely if i tell my dataceter that remove monitor command from my port it will solve the issue, but i need the port mirror, so what do you suggest to solve this?it seems its related to the n2k switch and i am looking for a way to solve this

Comment: I've seen this at some 2k FEX as they have very small buffer 12Mb for 8 uplinks.
When you switch LLFC this would still generate frames (question for TAC?). Try this "no hardware n2232p queue-limit" and you should get better performance at FEX. To view fex buffers you would need firstly "attach fex xxx" at switch. How many uplinks do you use for 2k -> 5k setup?

Comment: when i receive this error it just affect on my port mirroring ? other traffic on that port working without issue, right? also all flowcontrol on al of my switches are off.

Comment: this is not an error is just notification that bad thing about/might happen if my answers been beneficial for you please don't forget to mark as correct answer. Thank you. Disabling flow control between switches is a bad thing to do. Is like driving on the highway in opposite direction and closing eye pretending nothing bad will happen.

Comment: so can i ignore this error ? and it does not affect on my network such packet loss or .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Disable flow control.  It's an alright feature on edge ports but should not be used elsewhere in your topology.

The purpose of Ethernet flow control is to reduce the amount of traffic introduced into the network which ultimately will be lost due to congestion; and to give end-nodes the opportunity to buffer data in their presumably-larger memories (e.g. OS queue) rather than have packets be discarded.

When you do this in the core of your network the effects are less-predictable and not beneficial.  Unless you're sure you know what you're doing, never use Ethernet flow control except at the network edge.  That does not include your transit or peering -- in this context, think of these as ports carrying flows to/from many of your network nodes (servers or users) and thus not part of "edge" in this context.

Comment: all flow controls are off.